# How do you remove the top bar from Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line

I was wondering if there is any way to remove the top bar on ubuntu's terminal for a cleaner look, Does anyone knows how?

Comment: can [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420452/how-to-hide-title-bar-for-a-specific-window) help you?

Comment: its quite confusing to me, thanks for the help tho.